# cordova plugin - meta-data in plugin.xml need to change for different project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to develop a Cordova plugin，which need to add a meta-data to android manifest.xml.

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">

  <meta-data
    android:name="key"
    android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
</config-file>
```

For anyone who will use this plugin, the `key` will be different. so if they want to use this plugin, they need to revise plugin.xml. As you know, this is the source code of plugin, a plugin user may never want to revise. So is there any other place, where I can make this configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this plugin，I solve the issue
https://github.com/mircoc/cordova-plugin-settings-hook